# Local Struct Variables vs Assignement of Structs

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int* b; 
} test; 

void foo(test* t){
    test u = {.a = 1; .b = (test*) malloc(3*sizeof(test))}
    u.b[0]=0;
    u.b[1]=1;
    u.b[2]=2;
    *t=u; 
}

void main(){
    test t;
    foo(&t);
}
```

The variable u is local to the function foo.

**My question is:** What happens with the variables u and t after
the function foo is executed?

```
1. Is the memory allocated for u.a released? 
2. Is the memory allocated for u.b freed?
3. Is t.b equal to the vector [0,1,2]?
```

Comment: Also you need to pass `&t` as argument to `foo()` function. `foo(t);` --> `foo(&t);`

Comment: The term "free" is actually only used to `free` something that was previously allocated with `malloc`. Otherwise the term "released" is more appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the comments. corrected now.

Comment: @verifying see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens with the variables u and t after the function foo is executed?

nothing with the code you give because it cannot compile for a lot of reasons :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
c.c: In function ‘foo’:
c.c:7:21: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘;’ token
     test u = {.a = 1; .b = (test*) malloc(3*sizeof(test))}
                     ^
c.c:8:5: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘u’
     u.b[0]=0;
     ^
c.c:11:6: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘test * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’ from type ‘test {aka struct <anonymous>}’
     t=u;
      ^
c.c:6:16: warning: parameter ‘t’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
 void foo(test* t){
                ^
c.c: At top level:
c.c:14:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main(){
      ^~~~
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:16:9: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘foo’
     foo(t);
         ^
c.c:6:6: note: expected ‘test * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’ but argument is of type ‘test {aka struct <anonymous>}’
 void foo(test* t){
      ^~~
```

---

A corrected version of the code is :

```
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int* b; 
} test; 

void foo(test* t){
    test u = {.a = 1, .b = (int*) malloc(3*sizeof(test))};
    u.b[0]=0;
    u.b[1]=1;
    u.b[2]=2;
    *t=u; 
}

int main(){
    test t;
    foo(&t);
}
```

Using the corrected version :

> 1. Is the memory allocated for u.a freed?

*u* is a local variable, it is not allocated in the heap but placed in the stack, after returning from *foo* the local variable does not exist anymore, so the same for the field *u.a*

> 2. Is the memory allocated for u.b freed?

the memory allocated by *malloc* whose pointer was saved in *u.b* is not freed, but the memory used for *u.b* is in the stack as for *u.a* or *u* itself so after the return that fields does not exist anymore

> 3. Is t.b equal to the vector [0,1,2]?

yes after the correction copying deeply, *t.b* in *main* points to the array allocated by *malloc* then set in *foo*

if you add `printf("%d %d %d\n", t.b[0], t.b[1], t.b[2]);` at the end of *main* it will print `0 1 2`

Comment: It is preferable to explain C semantics in the way they are described in the C standard. This answer subtly mixes abstract semantics with practical implementations. When refers to something being in “the heap” or “the stack,” it is talking about specific implementations, which are fine for examples but are not correct statements of C semantics. And, in C semantics, when `foo` returns, `u` ceases to exist. But this answer described `u` as “placed on the stack.” If `u` is regarded as on the stack, it it not correct to say it “does not exist anymore,” because the stack does not go away…

Comment: … when a function returns (although data below the stack pointer becomes unreliable). The statement “the memory used… does not exist anymore” is false. The memory exists. It is in a chip in the computer. It did not vanish in a puff of smoke when the routine returned. When you mix different descriptions, the writing becomes imprecise and unclear. And it is not enough that you or experienced readers “know what you mean.” Answers are for people who do **not** know what you mean. They need to be written clearly using a consistent and correct model.

Comment: @EricPostpischil frankly speaking it is not honest nor serious to get two parts of a sentence removing the middle and from that to say it is wrong. I **never** said "the memory does not exist anymore". What do you will think if I do the same from your answer ? ;-) It is also not gentle to consider the OP stupid ...

Comment: When a criticism shows me a potential improvement in my answer, I consider it and sometimes edit the answer. I have done that many times. The fact is this answer mixes models and could be better written.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you, and I do the same when I think this is justified, but here you push the plug too far ^^ (not sure that french expression can be translated like that)